# Add parameter using htaccess on condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting

This will be a simple for those familiar with Apache rules.

### Situation

Using Alipay for a payment platform, the return URL cannot feature any of your own URL parameters (be it GET or POST). However, I am using Joomla and specifically Akeeba subscriptions. This component expects a parameter in the URL in accordance with the payment platform in question.

I want to detect (through one of Alipay's URL parameters) when a return page is hit and add the extra parameter.

### Example (domain and page redacted)

```
http://...?
    currency=HKD&
    total_fee=2.00&
    out_trade_no=211&
    trade_no=2014040100276615&
    trade_status=TRADE_FINISHED
```

### Desired outcome

```
http://...?
    currency=HKD&
    total_fee=2.00&
    out_trade_no=211&
    trade_no=2014040100276615&
    trade_status=TRADE_FINISHED&
    paymentmethod=alipay
```

The simple addition of a &paymentmethod=alipay

### Problem

I can't seem to get Apache to pick up the rule; here are a couple of attempts so far. Please note, I definitely can use .htaccess and don't need to change RewriteBase.

```
-- Attempt 1 --
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} out_trade_no=
RewriteRule ^out_trade_no paymentmethod=alipay&out_trade_no [R,L,QSA]

-- Attempt 2 --
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)out_trade_no=(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}&paymentmethod=alipay [L,R=301,QSA]
```

### Progress

Combining the two, I have made progress but, now seem to have the Rewrite part spamming "paymentmethod=alipay" which seems to cause an error.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} out_trade_no=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !paymentmethod=
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}&paymentmethod=alipay [R,L]
```

Now getting a redirect chain until it automatically stops at a redirect limit

Comment: what is before the `?` in your URL?

Comment: Just a regular URL which can play no unique part in the selection process
http://my-domain.com/index.php/component/akeebasubs/callback?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to match a query string from that URL with that rewritecond you need to match the first one(`currency`). Which is the easiest.

Try this. It will send all the parameters you want.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\bcurrency=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?paymentmethod=alipay [R,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks fore the "easier to digest" RewriteRule, I like that. I am still experiencing an infinite amount of redirects though. DO you know how i could chain the "AND !paymentmethod" to that so that when the page redirects it doesn't add it all over again?

Comment: show a sample URL with the subfolders and all. Also make sure you are clearing your browser cache.